# Is it possible to use jmeter variables in an xpath assertion?

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I am using xpath assertions in a jmeter test suite but am having issues dealing with dynamic content in the responses I am receiving. Is there any way to use the jmeter variables I have defined inside of an xpath assertion? I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
/response/body/locationReports/locationReport[@deviceHandle = ${deviceHandle}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just discovered that it works by adding single quotes around the variable name like this

```
/response/body/locationReports/locationReport[@deviceHandle = '${deviceHandle}']
```